# How to ng-Repeat the Labels of uiSlider?

Tags: angularjs, uislider

I'm Using rzSlider for my survey Page.where as, I have my elements in $scope Array[].Now I wanna repeat the labels from my array in the place

(Very Bad, Good, Satisfied, Bad, Very Bad) Instead of (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) how could I?.

```
 $scope.Rating=['Very Bad','Good','Satisfied','Bad','Very Bad']

$scope.slider = {
                    value : 0,
                    options : {
                        floor : 0,
                        ceil : $scope.Rating.length,
                        showTicksValues : true,
                    }
                };
```

And I want to get the value OnChange of my rzSlider.

Check this fiddle :  https://jsfiddle.net/Lnmf26Lu/1/.

Hope to see you in my conversation

Answer (score 0):

Use the translate option.

```
    var rating = ['Very Good','Good','Satisfied','Bad','Very Bad'];

    $scope.slider = {
      value : 2,
      options : {
        floor : 0,
        ceil : rating.length - 1,
        showTicks: true,
        showTicksValues : true,
        translate: function (value) {
          if (value >= 0 && value < rating.length) {
            return rating[value];
            return '';
          }
        }
      };
    }
```

Here is the edited fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8t2zetkc/1/